# How to obtain distinct/unique rows from GenomicRanges object

Tags: r, bioinformatics, tidyverse, genomicranges

I have the following [GenomicRanges](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) object created with this:

```
library(GenomicRanges)
gr <- GRanges(seqnames = "chr1", strand = c("+", "-","-", "+"),ranges = IRanges(start = c(1,3,3,5), width = 3))
gr
```

That looks like this:

```
GRanges object with 4 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
      seqnames    ranges strand
         <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle>
  [1]     chr1       1-3      +
  [2]     chr1       3-5      -
  [3]     chr1       3-5      -
  [4]     chr1       5-7      +
```

What I want to do is to obtain the unique rows from there, yielding this (hand-coded)

```
GRanges object with 3 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
      seqnames    ranges strand
         <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle>
  [1]     chr1       1-3      +
  [2]     chr1       3-5      -
  [3]     chr1       5-7      +
```

How can I achieve that? In reality, I have around 9 million rows to process.

I can use this method but very2 slow:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 gr %>% 
   as.tibble() %>% 
   distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unique` to return the unique rows:

```r
library(GenomicRanges)

gr <- GRanges(seqnames = "chr1", strand = c("+", "-","-", "+"),ranges = IRanges(start = c(1,3,3,5), width = 3))
unique(gr)
#> GRanges object with 3 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
#>       seqnames    ranges strand
#>          <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle>
#>   [1]     chr1       1-3      +
#>   [2]     chr1       3-5      -
#>   [3]     chr1       5-7      +
#>   -------
#>   seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

If you are converting the object to a data.frame (as in your tidyverse solution), data.table's `unique` might be faster:

```r
library(data.table)

unique(as.data.table(gr))
#>    seqnames start end width strand
#> 1:     chr1     1   3     3      +
#> 2:     chr1     3   5     3      -
#> 3:     chr1     5   7     3      +
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with indexing:

```
gr[paste0(gr$seqnames, gr$ranges, gr$strand) %in% unique(paste0(gr$seqnames, gr$ranges, gr$strand)), ]
```

`paste0(gr$seqnames, gr$ranges, gr$strand)` will bind rows together into an identifiable character string representing a distinct combination of the variables. Then you use `%in%` to create a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` depending on whether those rows are unique. If not, the `[]` (indexing) will drop them.